# I need to add java codes that generated by protobuf in proto3 version to nutch 1.7

Tags: java, web-crawler, protocol-buffers, nutch

considering apache nutch crawler use protobuf in version 2 for distributing mode and in tika-parser for parse step, I need to add some codes to it that generated with proto3 syntax.
i meet some conflict-error when added protobuf 3.0.0 in build-path, these errors point to some of functions in protobuf's library classes.
programming is in eclipse, with java language, .proto files execute with protobuf 3.0.0-beta2 that install from [here](https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v3.0.0-beta-2/protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-2.tar.gz). can every one help me?

Answer (score 0):

Although is true that Nutch has some dependencies to protobuf-2.4.1 and protobuf-2.5.0 (that I could find in the github repository), this dependencies are from libraries used by Nutch and not used in Nutch directly: A quick search on the 2.x branch of apache/nutch: reveals that this libraries are used in the scope of the `parse-tika`, `lib-selenium` and `lib-htmlunit` plugins. What are you needing the protobuf v3 for? If you're trying to use it for one particular plugin, perhaps try to scope it to that plugin instead of a global dependency?

Comment: tnx for your response, I need it to use in fetcher class for communicate to another program, not in particular plugin, but generated java codes with protobuf v3 had some errors.
temporarily I build new jar file from protobuf v3 and its generated java codes with different name!

Comment: Well since the other uses of the protobuf library are scoped in the respective plugins this shouldn't be a problem, but I'm glad that it worked.

Comment: but I think this is, now we have two library of protobuf in 2 version with different name.this way fixed conflict of same name of two versions